# Give up focus to OS; Get rid of focus having same result as clicking on desktop background?

Tags: java, swing

I have an app and I would like to "give up" focus on the application to, I guess, the operating system. I would like it to have the same result as clicking on the desktop background.

I have looked at the `JFrame` methods and found nothing along the lines of `JFrame.loseFocus()`.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack it using java.awt.Robot

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.mouseMove(0,0); // or somewhere where you know your java windows aren't
r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
```

Comment: This is what I am currently doing, I guess I wanted something "cleaner". I'll hold out for other answers, but as it is, it seems this is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method like `JFrame.loseFocus()` and I don't think its even possible in java. Anyways, just out of curiosity, why do you want to do it?
Cheers.